# On-premise Bitbucket server error "Page not found"

Tags: jersey, bitbucket

we have problem with Bitbucket server as all pages display message "Page not found" with "We couldn´t find the page you requested".

Error message from log speak about jersey class:

```
`        at com.atlassian.stash.internal.request.DefaultRequestManager.doAsRequest(DefaultRequestManager.java:84)
        at com.atlassian.stash.internal.hazelcast.ConfigurableWebFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableWebFilter.java:38)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 243 frames trimmed
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class **com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes**
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ContextResolverFactory.init(ContextResolverFactory.java:86)
        at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$Sync.run(LazyReference.java:332)
        at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:150)
        ... 34 common frames omitted`
```

Error has started after Windows server OS update and restart Bitbucket service. Do you have any idea about source of problem? We are not Java developers as deep knowledge is not here.

Thank you